# Calling a method with an array value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a class like this

```
class someclass{
  public function somemethod(){}
}
```

Now I have an array:

```
$somearray['someclass']  = new someclass();
$somearray['somemethod'] = 'somemethod';
```

How can I fire them, I tried the following:

```
$somearray['someclass']->$somearray['somemethod']();
```

usign this I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Method name must be a string in ......................

Anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Comment: Your syntax is correct and an error should not be thrown.

Comment: Strange, I have simplified the code here, so maybe my fault lies elsewhere.

Comment: When you run your own simplified code, do you still get the error?

Comment: The fault was elsewhere in the code. Everything is ok now and this is the right syntax. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the error with the code provided (As @webbiedave pointed out the syntax is correct).

However you could cast the method name to a string before using it to ensure the method name is a string. This will ensure that even it is a user defined object with a `__toString()` method, it will be converted into its string representation.

```
$somearray['someclass']->{(string)$somearray['somemethod']}();
```

Comment: I tried this, and I get another error:Call to a member function () on a non-object

Comment: @Saif you have an issue elsewhere in your code. This indicates that `$somearray['someclass']` is not set or null. Also `$somearray['somemethod']` is not set or is null.

Comment: Yes the fault was somewhere else. Everything is ok now even without the casting. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't want to work that way (and I agree it should), you could try:

```
call_user_func(array($somearray['someclass'], $somearray['somemethod']));
```

Comment: +1 Nice method this works also. The code I  used worked also, I had some other mistake in my code. But this is definitely a nice alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$somearray['someclass']->{$somearray['somemethod']}();`

Comment: When I do this I get: Method name must be a string

Comment: Have you verified that `$somearray['somemethod']` actually contains a string?

Comment: I've tested that this works. Just make sure that it is a string.

Answer (score 0):

The following code was tested and seems to be want you want:

```
<?php


class someclass{
  public function somemethod(){ echo 'test'; }
}


$somearray['someclass']  = new someclass();
$somearray['somemethod'] = 'somemethod';

$somearray['someclass']->{$somearray['somemethod']}();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
foreach (get_class_methods(get_class(new someclass()) as $method) {
    $method();    
}
```